# Цикл внутри jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не могу понять как вывести в цикле те компоненты у которых одноименное состояние `true`.
Допустим у меня есть компонент `SettingMain` и `SettingPassword`, у первого состояние `true`, у второго `false`.

Отсюда вопрос - как отрендерить н-ное количество компонентов, у которых одноименное состояние `true`, чтобы не писать 10 раз одинаковое условие, отличающееся только названием компонента?

```
<div>
{
    this.state.SettingMain
    ? <SettingMain/>
    : null
}

{
    this.state.SettingPassword
    ? <SettingPassword/>
    : null
}
...еще нное кол-во компонентов...
</div>
```

Comment: [Что делать, если никто не отвечает на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)